# What DebuggerVisualizers are already existing within VisualStudio or .Net Framework?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What DebuggerVisualizers are already existing within VisualStudio or .Net Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886836/what-debuggervisualizers-are-already-existing-within-visualstudio-or-net-framewo)

A quite dumb question but i simply can't find the answer.

I have a self-written class that implements the `IList<T>` interface. Now i like to see the containing elements within Debugging like i would with any .Net `List<T>`.

To get this to work i think i have to provide the correct visualizer within the `DebuggerVisualizerAttribute`. After a little searching all i could find is [the folder for additional Visualizer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdakzs26.aspx). But there is just one for the DataSet.

But what are the types of all the Visualizer already available within Visual Studio (e.g. for string, List, etc.), so that i could provide the correct one for my implementation of something already available?